# how to store the primary key values to the foreign key at same time of save

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to the laravel and trying to store the **primary key** values of `patientid` to the **foreign key** of `patient_id` in address table

```
$patdet = $request->patdet;

foreach ($patdet as $patdets) {
    $pdet = new Patient();

    $pdet->fname = $patdets['fname'];
    $pdet->mname = $patdets['mname'];
    $pdet->lname = $patdets['lname'];
    $pdet->age = $patdets['age'];
    $pdet->blood_group = $patdets['bloodgroup'];
    $pdet->gender = $patdets['gender'];
    $ptid = $pdet->save();
}

$addr = $request->address[0];
$address = new Address;
$address->gps_lat = $addr['gps_lat'];
$address->gps_log = $addr['gps_long'];
$address->house_no = $addr['houseno'];
$address->zipcode = $addr['zip_code'];
$address->street = $addr['street'];
$address->chowk = $addr['chowk'];
$address->city = $addr['city'];
$address->patient_id = $patid->id;
$address->save();
```

I know that `$ptid` is a local variable and cannot be used in address table,  so how can I store it in address table?

Comment: do you have same address for all patient? you are saving patient use foreach but not address. Are you posting only 1 patient record or multiple?

Comment: is patient data saved in db?

Comment: if i put the static value to patient_id =1 then data are save to db , other wise it throws error undefine varaible. i have multipe array like contact, medicine , etc and they all are in loop ?

Comment: have you try the below code

Comment: it gives error  at 
    if($pdet > 0) saying that 
    object of class use App\Patient couldnot be converted to int

Comment: oh sorry I missed 1 thing. edited now check. You need to check id like  if($pdet->id > 0)

Comment: gives error undefined offset 0 at 
    if($pdet->id > 0)

Comment: $pdet record saved or not? if saved then error to save address

Comment: Please reply asap

Comment: $pdet records are not saved

Comment: echo $pdet->id; die; Use it after $pdet->save(); what you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and ask me if it doesn't work

```
foreach($request->patdet as $key => $patdets)
{
    $pdet = new Patient();

    $pdet->fname = $patdets['fname'];
    $pdet->mname =  $patdets['mname'];
    $pdet->lname =  $patdets['lname'];
    $pdet->age   =  $patdets['age'];
    $pdet->blood_group = $patdets['bloodgroup'];
    $pdet->gender  = $patdets['gender'];
    $pdet->save();
    $addr = $request->address[$key];
    if($pdet->id > 0 && !empty($addr)){
        $addrss = new Address;
        $addrss->gps_lat = $addr['gps_lat'];
        $addrss->gps_log = $addr['gps_long'];
        $addrss->house_no  = $addr['houseno'];
        $addrss->zipcode    =  $addr['zip_code'];
        $addrss->street    = $addr['street'];
        $addrss->chowk  = $addr['chowk'];
        $addrss->city   = $addr['city'];
        $addrss->patient_id = $pdet->id;
        $addrss->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    $patArray = $request->patdet;
    $addressArray = $request->address;
    $pId = array();
    foreach($patArray as $key => $patdets){
        $pdet = new Patient();
        $pdet->fname = $patdets['fname'];
        $pdet->mname =  $patdets['mname'];
        $pdet->lname =  $patdets['lname'];
        $pdet->age   =  $patdets['age'];
        $pdet->blood_group = $patdets['bloodgroup'];
        $pdet->gender  = $patdets['gender'];
        $pdet->save();
        $pId[$key] = ($pdet->id > 0) ? $pdet->id : 0;
    }
    foreach($addressArray as $key => $addr){
        $addrss = new Address;
        $addrss->gps_lat = $addr['gps_lat'];
        $addrss->gps_log = $addr['gps_long'];
        $addrss->house_no  = $addr['houseno'];
        $addrss->zipcode    =  $addr['zip_code'];
        $addrss->street    = $addr['street'];
        $addrss->chowk  = $addr['chowk'];
        $addrss->city   = $addr['city'];
        $addrss->patient_id = array_key_exists($key ,$pId) ? $pId[$key] : 0;
        $addrss->save();
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: it works only for the single data when i send multiple it gives me the error integrity constraint violation:1415 Cannot add or update a child row: foreign constraints key fail